# same query hitting two different indexes in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I'm working with mongoDB with two different set of indexes. my query is

```
db.coll.find({"time":"xyz","x":222, "y":62, "z":"dfd"})
```

There are two composite indexes

1. x+time
2. time+x+y+z

In this case, I did explain("executionStats") and results are different both the times,
some times it is hitting index#1 and sometimes index#2, any idea why it is hitting two different indexes??

Thanks.